# What does application context in Spring do?

Tags: java, spring

I asked a question yesterday ( [Using Spring in standalone apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9675130/using-spring-in-standalone-apps) ) on how you would use Spring in a standalone application. From that I learned that you only create the application context object once. So now the question is (even though it was partially answered in a comment) what happens when you create the application context?

Does Spring create the beans and wire them together when you say
`new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("some.xml")` ?

I am not sure if I understand the boot strapping, and why it is like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea behind the ApplicationContext in Spring is that in order to properly inject objects where they are needed, some *thing* needs to be aware of the configuration the user specifies and inject dependencies based on this configuration.

The ApplicationContext is the *thing* that understands the user's wishes in terms of where and what should be injected (as well as other things such as AOP pointcuts and such) based on the configuration a user provides, either through an xml file or annotations.

Comment: How about some references for more information: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will parse the bean definition file , it will create the beans , give them the dependencies,

The easiest way to debug is to go with the output print statements,

Put the statements in constructor & setter methods and try different possibilities to track the flow